# How would you call someone who is a party pooper who doesn’t want to do anything

Tags: definition

For instance, someone goes to a hotel as a gateway and enjoy but they rather go to the store instead of eating a breakfast in the hotel because is too expensive and the other one gets dissapointed or someone is too excited to do something but he says mmm idk maybe we could do someone else less complicated

Answer (score 2):

That kind of sounds like me from time to time, so "Andrew"?  :D

Seriously though:  "Party pooper" is the slang expression that comes to mind, but here are some related slang expressions:

> **grinch**: Someone who generally dislikes merriment and fun, especially Christmas-related activities (from the famous Dr. Seuss story "How the Grinch Stole Christmas")
>
> **killjoy**: literally "someone who kills the joy", (slightly dated)
>
> **sourpuss**: "puss" is slang for "face" so someone whose face is wrinkled up like they're eating something sour, and has a similar expression when asked to do something they don't want to do. (slightly dated)
>
> **spoilsport**: someone who "spoils" the "sport" (fun) in an activity (slightly dated).
>
> **stick-in-the-mud**: someone who doesn't like to try new things, as if they are "stuck" in one place (slightly dated)
>
> **wet blanket**: You can throw a wet blanket onto a fire to put it out, in the same way this person douses all the excitement and fun of an activity (dated)
>
> **buzzkill**:  A "buzz" is the "high" you get from some intoxicant, in the same way the feeling from some exciting activity.  This person "kills" the "buzz".

My generation would be likely to use "buzzkill", but I couldn't tell you what the current generation would use.  Maybe just *"boring"*.

Comment: It's surprising how many of those you've labeled as "dated" or "slightly dated".

Comment: @J.R.  It based on how uncomfortable I imagine I'd feel using them, if I was a teenager.  There must be some new slang for these that the kids are using.

Answer (score 0):

“**girlfriend**"?

Seriously though, the example about breakfast is more like **skinflint** or **penny-pinching**.